# Wind direction via magnetometer and accelerometer

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm hanging a ball with sensors from a string to measure wind direction.

Calculating the tilt is relatively easy:

```
theta = acos(dot(a, a0)/dot(norm(a),norm(a0)));
```

where `a` is tilted accelerometer vector, and `a0` is the starting point (i.e. hanging straight down).

Heading:

```
heading = atan(mag_y/mag_x);
```

I can also get heading via the sensors proprietary sensor fusion algorithm (which is a lot more accurate).

My question is how do I calculate the wind direction? How do I know which way it is tilting?

[image: Clarifying image]

Edit:

Accelerometers measure acceleration. At rest perfectly perpendicular to earth, the sensor should measure (0, 0, 9.8). Note that some accelerometers gives amount of G's. In that case it would be (0, 0, 1).

Magnetometers measure earth's magnetic field. Since it runs north and inward towards the center of the earth (in the northern hemisphere), in a perfect world the sensor would output (X, 0, Z), where X and Z is around 25-65 µTesla.

Edit 2:

I think I solved it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

[image: Solution]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Dumb answer: The wind direction is in whichever direction the ball is going ...

Comment: I'm not an expert in accelerometers, so do you mind explaining on what data your accelerometer collects and what those variables represent? For example, tilted acceloremeter vector means nothing to me (and maybe to other mathematicians), so it would be nice if you could explain more on what these variables represent and what data you are given.

Comment: @MattiP. Well, you're not wrong. But which way is it?

Comment: @AlanAbraham Of course. See edit.

Comment: @William So the way I see it, you have 3 accelerometer sensors that output the relative strengths of the gravitational acceleration in the direction of the 3 axes of a coordinate space that is fixed wrt to the ball. Is that right? Also, just to make sure I understand the variables correctly, is this true: $a_x^2+a_y^2+a_z^2=g^2$?